# Python Requests logging problems. 403 error

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I am trying to create a login for one of the web sites: "https://mediamarkt.pl". Unfortunately I am getting an 403 error. Can you please help with this case?

Here is my code:

```
import requests



s = requests.Session()

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

headers = {

    'Authority':'mediamarkt.pl',
    'Method':'POST',
    'Path': '/api/v1/msg',
    'User-Agent': user_agent,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Referer': 'https://mediamarkt.pl/pl/myaccount/auth/login?redirectURL=%2F',
}


def login_site(email, password):

    login_url = 'https://mediamarkt.pl/api/v1/msg'
    form_data = {
        'email': email,
        'password': password,
        'mms-login-form__login-button':'Zaloguj się',
        }
    login = s.post(login_url, data=form_data, headers=headers)

    if login.status_code == 200:
        print("Login successful!")
        print("Server response:")
        print(login.text)
    else:
        print(f"Login error. Response status: {login.status_code}")


email = "XYZ@gmail.com"

password = "XYZ123!"

login_site(email, password)
```

I've tried to add some other headers... still 403 error.

Comment: share error you got

Comment: Login error. Response status: 403

Comment: are you able to login via cli or postman, probably some check issue, try to see browser what are they expecting and what difference is there in this request and browser one

Comment: There is no problem while logging manually via browser